# JavaScript Namespaces + Setter

Tags: javascript

Well, I'm using object orientation in JavaScript, but instead of using `new`, I just call the method from the namespace. In the moment, I have the following code:

```
var Component = {
    Button: function(_text, use_image) {
        button = $.createElement('button')
        if (use_image != false)
        {
            button.innerHTML = _text;
        }
        else
        {
            button.innerHTML = _text
        }
        var text = _text
        return button
    }
}
```

When I want to return a button, I do:

```
x = Component.Button("Click me")
```

And after I can use x. But if I want to change the text of x, I must use `x.textContent`. I'd like to instantiate this and use a setter to apply its text, this way:

```
x = new Component.Button("Click me")
x.text = "Don't click me"
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(x)
```

And if I try to apply the setter `text`, it becomes global, I want to have a unique for each button. Mix namespaces with get/set.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should you a prototypical approach to get instance specific variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way can be like, I am not sure if this is the best approach. Looking for more answers

```
var Component = {
    Button: function(_text, use_image) {
        var button = {
            node : document.createElement('button'),
            setText : function(txt){this.node.innerHTML = txt;}
        };        
        if(_text){button.setText(_text);}
        return button;
    }
};

x = Component.Button("Click me");
x.setText("Don't click me");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(x.node);

y = Component.Button("Click me2");
y.setText("Don't click me2");
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(y.node);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2LCyn/

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
var Component = (function($){

    var buttonCount = 0;

    function Button(text, use_image){
        this.id = ++buttonCount;
        this.text = text;
        this.use_image = use_image;
        this.$element = $('<button/>').text(text);
        this.bindEvents();
    }

    Button.prototype.bindEvents = function(){
        var that = this;
        this.$element.on('click', function(){
            console.log('hello, I\'m button ' + that.id);
        });
    };

    Button.prototype.setText = function(text){
        this.text = text;
        this.$element.text(text);
    };

    return {
        Button: Button
    }

})(jQuery);

var button1 = new Component.Button('hello', false);
button1.setText('helloooo');
$('body').append(button1.$element);

var button2 = new Component.Button('world', true);
$('body').append(button2.$element);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ATmAx/1/